# Microsoft graph API: finding event by iCalUid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to decline one instance of recurring meeting. I only have masterSerieId, iCalId, time of that instance.

Do you know how I could cancel that instance?

Do I have to query using masterId and time of the instance to find event id or there is a way I would just find eventId using iCalId?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [OData query options](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356) to filter on just the event that has that particular iCalUId.

For instance:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=iCalUId eq '<your iCalUId>'`

Comment: Using this option I obtain 'client error'' , Invalid filter clause . It doesn't seem to work  .

Comment: @Berni: Works for me without problems.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly the calendar view endpoint does not include events which are part of an event series if you match against a given iCalUId.
So if an event has a seriesMasterId which is not null, you wont find it by filtering for the iCalUId.

Comment: Did you figure out a way of doing this? Using the calendarview API seems like it could work, but that also requires knowing the time range of the meeting instance (and the API only allows a max of 5 years).