# Microsoft Graph API question: how do I get event instance data via iCalUId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Here's my problem: I am using Microsoft Graph API v1.0 and would like to get the details of an instance of a recurring calendar event. All I got is the iCalUId of the instance.

I tried this call:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=iCalUId eq 'the value of the iCalUId'
This was also suggested in [Microsoft graph API: finding event by iCalUid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421463/microsoft-graph-api-finding-event-by-icaluid).

This works fine for single events.
But it does not work for instances of recurring meetings: then the call returns an empty value. I just verified this in the Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Am I doing something wrong (even though the iCalUId is unique to the instance)? Is there a different call I could use?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because instances of recurring meetings don't actually exist on the server. When you use the `/me/events` endpoint, you are getting only single-instance and series masters events - it does not trigger the server to expand recurring events into individual instances.

To get server-side expansion, you have to use the `/me/calendarview` endpoint. This does require that you specify a date range though. For example, this works:

```
GET /me/calendarview?startDateTime=2020-01-31T00:00:00
&endDateTime=2020-02-29T00:00:00&
$filter=iCalUId eq '040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00807E40204756DC3EEFFE5CC01000000000000000010000000FCE197631C1A2E4C89172A4115BEB7B5'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I don't know the date range I am afraid I cannot really use this call. Is there any other way?

Maybe I don't understand the logic of event instance iCalUIds yet. I thought an iCalUId is a user-independent identifier of an event or instance of an event series. 
e.g. when you send a /me/calendarview request, its result would include event instances which come with iCalUIds. 
What would be the use of these iCalUIds if you can't use them to retrieve the instances?

Comment: You could set your time range to a fairly large window, but I hear you. The API just isn't set up to retrieve things directly via iCalUId. You could give feedback and a feature request to the API at our UserVoice: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/

Comment: Right, if you use a really large time range like several years, the performance is no longer  acceptable. Thanks for hint, I have posted the idea: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39585670-offer-an-api-to-retrieve-instances-of-events-via-i

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. calendarview API only returns occurrences and exceptions by iCalUID. It does not return serierMaster by iCalUID. For getting seriesmaster by iCalUID, one must use /me/events. What a mess!

Comment: The calendarview API has a maximum time range of 5 years also, so if you just guess a time range based on today +- some amount, eventually you'll stop finding an event that does still exist