# How to create an event with extensions for attendees in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am creating events with [schema extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using graph api.

Btw, I can create an event with the extensions for an organizer, but the extensions won't be included in the same event but attendee's event.

In the other hands, the organizer's event does have the extensions, but the same event sent to attendees does not have the extensions.

Ideally, I want to keep the extensions in the attendee's event as well.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying the above with personal account/MSA or work/school account?

Comment: @Dev Sure. And I was able to get the event including extension from the organizer by filtering `iCalUid`.

Comment: Awesome @hotcakedev. Glad to see that you updated answer below. It will be useful to others in the community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering how to handle the same event but different for several attendees.

Because the created event `id` was different for each attendee.

And finally, I realized that [`iCalUid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) was the same to the event for each attendee, so I was able to get the event from the organizer by filtering `iCalUid` like the following Graph API. (Reference: [Microsoft graph API: finding event by iCalUid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421463/microsoft-graph-api-finding-event-by-icaluid))

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{organizer_id}}/calendar/events?expand=extensions(filter=id eq 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.{{extension_name}}')&filter=iCalUId eq {{iCalUid}}
```